abort/stop a postgres query from node, TypeScript?
I have a little express server which queries data from a PostgreSQL db.
this looks like this:
app.get('/query_tile/:z/:x/:y', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const t0 = performance.now()
    const setHeader = () => {
        res.set('Content-Encoding', 'br');
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-protobuf');
        res.set('Vary', 'Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers');
        res.set('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=tile_${z}_${x}_${y}.mvt`);
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    }
    const { z, x, y } = req.params;
    const useCache = req.query.useCache !== 'false'; // use cache by default

    console.log(`REQUEST tile_${z}_${x}_${y}`);
    console.log(`http://localhost:3001/query_tile/${z}/${x}/${y}`)
    const cacheKey = `tile_${z}_${x}_${y}`;
    let cachedData = null;
    if (useCache) {
        cachedData = await redis.getBuffer(cacheKey);
    }
    if (cachedData) {
        const t1 = performance.now()
        console.log(`SENDING CACHED tile_${z}_${x}_${y}, took ${(t1 - t0) / 1000}s`);
        setHeader()
        res.send(cachedData);

    } else {
        try {
            const { rows } = await client.query('SELECT query_cityjson($1, $2, $3)', [z, x, y]);
            const data = rows[0].query_cityjson;
            if (data) {

                const compressedData = brotliCompressSync(data);
                // send data as cached Data to redis. TTL 10 min (600s  )
                await redis.set(cacheKey, compressedData, "EX", 6000);

                const t1 = performance.now()
                console.log(`SENDING DB tile_${z}_${x}_${y}, took ${(t1 - t0) / 1000}s`);

                setHeader()
                res.send(compressedData);
            } else {
                res.sendStatus(404)
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            res.sendStatus(404)
        }
    }
});

the issue I am having is that I want to be able to cancel the requests, if the http query was aborted.
so on the client side, I have a map application which uses fetch with an abort controller to abort the queries if not needed anymore. this works, but does not stop the db queries.
Since for example in PGAdmin I can stop queries in the db there must be a way to do the same from here too - but I just cannot find one.
can anyone point me in the right direction how I would do something like this?
Thanks a lot!

There's a .cancel() method in client but it's not documented. Also there are various issues regarding cancelling queries in the repo
